# Unable to enter data into cells in sc

Tags: macos, unix, spreadsheet, macports

I'm trying to use `sc`, the classic Unix spreadsheet calculator, mainly because I want to be able to look at some csv files nicely formatted in my terminal. I installed `sc` 7.16 but am seeing some strange behavior that I can't seem to fix.

When I start up `sc`, if I type, say `=`, to try to set a numeric value for the first cell `A0`, and it gives me a prompt like so

```
i> let A0 =
```

so then I type 1 and press enter

```
i> let A0 = 1
```

and then I get

```
A0 (10 2 0) []
syntax error: let A0<= = 1
```

This seems unexpected and I'm not sure how to even go forward. I see the same sort of problem when trying to read in `.sc` files.

Further details: running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and installed sc via macports (though I'll note that I also tried building from the sc 7.16 source and but the version I got from this displayed the exact same error).

Comment: I can confirm that the procedure you describe works as expected on my Linux. You're not doing anything wrong as far as I can tell.

Comment: Given that, I may have to solve this problem with the build myself. Anyone have any ideas on what's happening here that I might be able to fix?

Comment: It would seem to be complaining about the `A0` in the entry command, but I don't have any clue as to why.  (if I remember correctly the position of an error is indicated by the `<=` "arrow" in the syntax error message.